# Converting .asc files to points?

Tags: qgis, ascii, files

I have multiple wind data at varying heights in `.asc`-file format.

I want to interpolate them in QGSI but it seems I can't even display the points even if I click add raster. It's still on a table.

How can I achieve points out of `.asc`-file?

Comment: Try to export the ASC file to XYZ format, and import the result as delimited text point data.

Comment: Could you share some test data? A few lines would be enough.

Comment: (  0, 1299); 0.0; 0.0; 0.0; 0.0; 0.0; 0. something like that